# What is the difference between "allein zu sein" und "allein sein"

Tags: difference

Heute habe ich einen Text im Internet gelesen, und ich habe nicht verstanden, was der Unterschied zwischen erstem Satz und zweitem Satz ist.

Satz 1: "Allein zu sein macht dir vielleicht Angst"
Satz 2: "Allein sein macht dir vielleicht Angst"

Comment: I'm no native speaker, but I think the 2nd one should be: > Alleinsein macht dir vielleicht Angst. See [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Alleinsein)

Comment: It helps to keep the question and the question title in the same language; use English or German, whichever you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied in der Bedeutung ist marginal, und liegt im Wesentlichen im Stil oder Ausdruck:

> Allein zu sein macht dir vielleicht Angst
> --> Das Subjekt des Satzes ist ein erweiterter Infitiv mit zu. Das englische Äquivalent wäre sowas wie "Maybe being alone does frighten you"

> Alleinsein macht dir vielleicht Angst --> Hier ist das Subjekt des Satzes ein Substantiv mit der gleichen Bedeutung wie der erweiterte Infinitiv oben. Das englische Äquivalent wäre sowas wie "Maybe solitude does frighten you".

Comment: Why is there a "not" in the English equivalent? Shouldn't it be: //Being alone may scare you.// ??

Comment: Good question. You are totally right. Fixed